# How to connect to sql server with dynamic IP Address

Tags: sql-server, network, tcpip

I have installed sql server express edition 2014 on my machine. And I am connecting to it with CRM using my local machine's IP address.

The problem here is my IP address allocated to my machine is dynamic and changes every day when I log in, which makes it impossible for me to connect to CRM (as the IP address changes obviously).

What to do in that case? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: *What to do in that case?* Use static address if possible, or static lease otherwise. Ask your system/network administrator for it.

Comment: I did that but it creates other problems like i am not able to connect to internet/ ip conflict with other systems etc. can you suggest anything else apart from that please.

Comment: Can you not use a net name or computer name (IE DNS Name)

Comment: *i am not able to connect to internet/ ip conflict with other systems etc.* This means that you set some static address within DHCP scope by yourself, without consult with admins. It's basically a diversion. Contact administrator group of your network. They will give you personal static address or will set static lease for your station.

Comment: And one more variant is to install virtual machine and move SQL server into it. It will not interfere with your network.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of connecting via IP address, connect to your machine's name. If you're connecting locally, you can use LOCALHOST as the name, or just a period ("."), which connects you to your local default instance.

Comment: Loopback address may be not safe for OP. If you offer to change the connection properties, it will be more logical option to work through named pipes.

Comment: Why would it not be safe?

Comment: Not would. May.

Comment: Right, why may it not be safe? You need to be more specific when you're casting someone's answer as not safe.

Comment: I think CRM which OP uses tells about localhost in the documentation for configuring the connection. Often localhost is default address for connection settings. But OP uses NIC's address. Why? I had met at least 2 software products which refuses to work via localhost with error similar to "invalid address". That's why I suggested that localhost might not be safe option.

Comment: OK, so that's not like it's dangerous. When you say something isn't safe, that implies that it's dangerous - there's no risk here.

Answer (score 1):

Brent's suggestions of using your machine name, or LOCALHOST or just "." are all great ones, I would also suggest using the loop back address of 127.0.0.1